# Apache Solr 4.6.0 installation and compatibility with Drupal7

Tags: search

I'm having difficulties installing Apache Solr. The latest version that I downloaded was 4.6.0.  But all Drupal documentation and tutorials (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ori-VvvH1Aw) are talking about 3.5.0.  While 3.5.0 is nowhere to be found on internet, 4.6.0 has a totally different directory structure, and there is no documentation on how to install this latest version on a server or on a local WAMP.  There is no mentioning of which Apache Solr versions are most recommended to work with Drupal?  Any help?

Comment: There's an excellent article here: http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-solr-use-drupal Which worked for me on 4.5.1. If you want to use Search API Solr then I wrote an example installation for Ubuntu 12.04 over here: https://drupal.org/node/2143715

Answer (score 21):

You aren't alone I had to scour the internet and read several articles before I truly understand all of this. I tried about three different methods until I finally got it right!

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu (with Tomcat7) it's even easier then most outline. I preferred this over Lullabot since when you install it through Ubuntu it's actually a service and less fiddling :)

## Install Java

```
apt-get install java7-jdk
```

## Install Tomcat

```
apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-admin
```

Once this is done you can get to `http://localhost:8080` and see that's it is all running properly.

**Note:** It's recommended to push the port to another one since 8080 is pretty common. If you want to do that use this code for that!

```
sudo sed -i s/8080/8983/g /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml
```

## Configure Tomcat

1. You will want to actually create a users account for Tomcat so that other people have to log into the admin (it keeps it safer).

   `nano /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml`
2. Then add these xml arguments between the `<tomcat-users>` tags

   `<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="!!somename!!" password="!!somepassword!!" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>`
3. Now you can restart tomcat again and view the admin page at  `http://localhost:8983/manager/html`

   `service tomcat7 restart`

## Install Solr

1. Download the latest [ApacheSolr here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr) (When I wrote this I got it working with 4.7)
2. Extract the files into a directory

### Copy Solr library files

Next we want to add the library files to Tomcat library directory. **Note:** You can also use symlinks if you prefer, but for the purpose of understand where everything goes I chose to place it directly in the directories

```
cp ~/solr-4.x.x/example/lib/ext/* /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/
```

It may be a good idea to also copy the java libraries from solr/dist/solrrj-lib/*

```
cp ~/solr-4.x.x/dist/solrj-lib/* /usr/local/tomcat7/lib/
```

### Copy Solr WAR app file

```
cp ~/solr-4.x.x/dist/solr-4.x.x.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/solr.war
```

## Setup Drupal ApacheSolr core

1. We first need to copy over the sample configuration files from ApacheSolr.

   `mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat7/solr
   cp -r ~/solr-4.x.x/example/solr/collection1/conf /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/`
2. Next grab the latest version of the apachesolr module https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr and unzip it

   `tar xvf apachesolr-*.tar.gz`
3. Syncronize the apachesolr configuration files (for Drupal) with your solr configuration

   `rsync -av apachesolr/solr-conf/solr-4.x/ /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/conf/`

**Note:** I found an error in which ApacheSolr refused to start due to duplicate errors. I reported that [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2306313) so you might want to look at the solution [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2107417) as at the time of writing this I could not get it running without that!

4. Create a core definition file to tell Apache Solr which cores are available.

   `nano /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/solr.xml`
5. Paste the following code inside that file

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <solr persistent="false">
      <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
        <core name="!!yourcorename!!" instanceDir="!!yourcoredir!!" />
       </cores>
     </solr>`

### Create Drupal core directory

This will create a new core in your system with that name. If you wish to add more you simply can repeat this step as well as the one above.

```
mkdir /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/!!yourcoredir!!
cp -r /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/conf /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/!!yourcoredir!!/
```

### Let's Make It Live

1. Your at the last stretch!! Let's put tomcat7 to sleep

   `service tomcat7 stop`
2. Now change the permissions on the tomcat directory

   `chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7`
3. Start it back up

   `service tomcat7 start`

## It's Live

You should be able to go to `http://localhost:8983/solr` and see a new core instance available! Now you can go ahead and configure drupal to point to that.

**Note:** Your new core is located at `http://localhost:8983/solr/!!yourcorename!!` to be used in the Drupal ApacheSolr module.

Credit and props goes out to [Pacoup](http://pacoup.com/2014/02/05/install-solr-4-6-with-tomcat-7-on-debian-7/)

Comment: Great guide. Under "configure Tomcat" it is missing the xml under step 2: "Then add these xml arguments between the tags"... no xml given.

Comment: Hmm it's there but you can't see it maybe cause of your browser? Let me try and change the output to fix that

Comment: Actually I just checked and I am using the proper code tags?

Comment: See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/s1jlunf.png

Comment: I fixed it. xml code needs to be placed between ` `

Comment: Weird I had also double checked the tags.. anyways thanks for fixing that!

Comment: BTW I noticed that you added the following _It may be a good idea to also copy the java libraries from solr/dist/solrrj-lib/*_ but I have never had to do that? ARe you sure that's required?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but that's what the article at Lullabot indicates (https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-solr-use-drupal). I figure it doesn't hurt to copy those library files as well, in case tomcat/solr ever needs them... (unused libraries won't hurt anything, but if you ever do need a library that's not there...) maybe just add some more clarification to that suggestion, and a link to Lullabot? Unless someone can give a more definitive answer?

Comment: Hm... alright I never needed them but you are right it can't hurt. I personally found the lullabot article extremely confusing which is why I put this up here :P

Comment: I am grateful for your solution here, however I had to comment out the default classloader lib settings to remove some annoying warning messages. See http://egeek.dk/cant-find-or-read-directory-to-add-to-classloader/

Comment: Can you actually modify the actual stackexchange to include how someone can comment out these things if they don't want to view messages. Referencing links is generally not encouraged since websites can die :/

Comment: Your site was unable to contact the Apache Solr server.

Comment: You need to make sure that the service is running.. also check the Apache Solr logs too!

Comment: I'm trying to setup the Solr. But the problem is now with Solr-5.x. Your answer is following 4.x and I see everywhere 4.x documentations. I don't know what is there in `/solr-4.x.x/example/solr/collection1/conf` and I don't find it in 5.x version. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had Solr 4.6.X working Ubuntu 14.04 with tomcat6. But tomcat6 isn't available for Ubuntu 16.04 and this guide saved my butt. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for ApacheSolr 4.9.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to Solr 4 have been discussed in the issue queue: https://drupal.org/node/1676224

The issue contains a number of links to sandbox sites and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

All solr version should work with Drupal as long you've module which supports it.

For example [Apachesolr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module, has [configuration files](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/apachesolr/tree/solr-conf) for: Solr: 3.x and 4.x.

For [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module, you can find the [configuration files](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/search_api_solr/tree/solr-conf) for Solr: 3.x, 4.x and 5.x, so it shouldn't be a problem.

How to install Solr, it's another thing. There are many ways of doing it. Few examples below.

### Installation

#### OS X

Simplest way is to install latest Apache Solr using Homebrew, e.g.:

```
brew install solr
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/solr/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
brew services start solr # Or just: solr start
```

Now installed Solr instance is accessible at: http://localhost:8983/

#### Debian/Ubuntu

Simplest way is to install Solr via `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install solr-tomcat
```

#### via Puppet

Use Puppet manifest to install Solr. Here is one [solr4-tomcat.pp](https://github.com/mycognitive/puppet-lamp/blob/master/solr4-tomcat.pp) example.

#### Manually (4.x or 5.x)

```bsh
$ VER=4.10.4 # Solr version.
$ TOMCAT_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7
$ sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-admin
$ sudo sed -i.org 's|port=\"8080\"|port=\"8983\"|g' /etc/tomcat?/server.xml
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/solr/home/collection1/conf /opt/solr/data
$ cd /opt/solr
$ curl -s http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/$VER/solr-$VER.tgz | sudo tar zxvf -
$ sudo cp -v /opt/solr/solr-$VER/dist/solr-$VER.war $TOMCAT_BASE/webapps/solr.war
$ sudo cp -v /opt/solr/solr-$VER/example/lib/ext/*.jar /opt/solr/solr-$VER/dist/solrj-lib/*.jar /opt/solr/solr-$VER/example/resources/log4j.properties $TOMCAT_BASE/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib
$ curl -s http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/search_api_solr-7.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz | sudo tar zxvf -
$ sudo cp -v search_api_solr/solr-conf/4.x/* home/collection1/conf/
$ sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart
```

Check if it is working at: http://localhost:8983

---

See also:

- [Example installation on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://www.drupal.org/node/2143715) at Drupal.org
- [Deploying procedures for GNU/Linux distros based on Debian.](https://sourceforge.net/p/maritaca/wiki/deployProcedures2/)
- [Installing and Configuring Tomcat 6 and Apache Solr for Drupal 6 on Ubuntu](http://drupal.cocomore.com/blog/installing-and-configuring-tomcat-6-and-apache-solr-drupal-6-ubuntu)
- [Installing Solr for use with Drupal](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-solr-use-drupal) at Lullabot
- [Search API vs Apache Solr Search Integration in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/15508/1908)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it's described in Drupal Community Documentation ([Installing Solr on Tomcat](https://www.drupal.org/node/716632)):

#### CentOS

> This walk-through assumes you already have Tomcat installed. If you
>   don't it is probably easier to just use WHM and install it there and
>   rebuild apache. Point and click is what I say.
>
> Once you have Tomcat installed you can verify its installation by
>   going to:
>
> ```
> domain.com:8080
> ```
>
> You should see the default Tomcat page. If not, ask someone for help.
>   If you don't, you are hurting the next person who comes along with the
>   same issue. If we didn't want to help we wouldn't be Open Source.
>
> Download your a copy of Solr. If you don't know where to get it,
>   google it.
>
> To make things easier now and in the future, find your Tomcat
>   installation
>
> ```
> $ locate tomcat
> ```
>
> Create a soft link like so:
>
> ```
> ln -s /my/tomcat/location /tomcat
> ```
>
> If you did it right you should be able to just
>
> ```
> $ /tomcat
> ```
>
> in sshd and get to your directory.
>
> I will be using the `/lib` directory for my example. If you don't have
>   one, create it with `mkdir /lib` command.
>
> 1. Extract Solr to temporary location, for my sake, I just get the zip file from Solr mirrors.
>
>    ```
>    $ unzip apache-solr-1.4.1.zip /lib/
>    ```
>
>    Build your Solr
>
>    ```
>    $ cd /lib/solr
>    $ ant dist (you should see it building something.)
>    ```
> 2. Rename your war file for ease of use.
>
>    ```
>    $ cd /lib/apache-solr-1.4.1
>    $ cd dist
>    $ mv apache-solr-1.4.1.war solr.war  (this just renames it without asking you)
>    $ dir  (check to make sure it worked. you should see solr.war)
>    ```
> 3. Copy `solr.war` to `/lib/solr/example`
>
>    ```
>    $ cp solr.war /lib/solr/example
>    $ cd /lib/solr/example
>    $ dir  (verify that the solr.war is in the directory, you should also see the familiar start.jar file there)
>    ```
> 4. Copy the xml files from your apachesolr location. Usually it will be:
>
>    ```
>    $ cp /home/YOUR_NAME/www/modules/apachesolr/*.xml /lib/solr/example/solr/conf</code>
>    ```
> 5. Create an xml file in Tomcat to tell it to run Solr at Tomcat start-up
>
>    ```
>    $ cd /tomcat
>    $ cd /conf/Catalina/localhost
>    $ vi solr.xml
>    ```
>
>    Paste this into your new file:
>
>    ```
>    <code>
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <Context docBase="/solr/example/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true" >
>       <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/solr/example/solr" override="true" /> 
>    </Context>
>    </code>
>    ```
>
>    The two values you should be customizing are Context::docBase (to
>      point to your .war file) and Environment::value (to point to your solr
>      directory). Note that in this example the .war file is in the solr
>      directory, which is a fine pattern to follow.
>
>    {Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> and then `:w`} and then {Press Escape Key
>      and then `:q`}
> 6. Restart Tomcat using WHM for ease. It's under Restart Services. Then go here:
>
>    ```
>    yourdomainname.com:8080/solr/admin
>    ```
>
>    You may get this error:
>
>    > false in null -------------------------------------------------------------
>    >     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot create
>    >     directory: /usr/share/solr/data/index at
>    >     org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:398) at
>    >     org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:546) at ...
>
>    Don't panic. I gatcha!
>
>    Go to `solrconfig.xml` again
>
>    ```
>    $ cd /solr/example/solr/conf
>    $ vi solrconfig.xml
>    ```
>
>    and modify this line:
>
>    ```
>    <!--<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:./solr/data}</dataDir>-->
>    ```
>
>    to
>
>    ```
>    <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:./solr/data}</dataDir>
>    ```
>
>    Restart Tomcat again and go here:
>
>    ```
>    yourdomainname.com:8080/solr/admin
>    ```
>
>    **DO THIS IF YOU HAVEN'T ALREADY:**
>
>    Go to your schema.xml file in `/lib/solr/example/solr/conf`:
>
>    ```
>    $ vi schema.xml
>    ```
>
>    Add this in the section just after `<field>`:
>
>    ```
>      <field dest="host" source="host"/>
>      <field dest="segment" source="segment"/>
>      <field dest="boost" source="boost"/>
>      <field dest="digest" source="digest"/>
>      <field dest="tstamp" source="tstamp"/>
>    ```
>
>    Save it and exit {Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> Button) `:w` (Press
>      <kbd>Enter</kbd>) then (Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> Button) `:q` (Press
>      <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
>
>    If you are using Nutch then go here and [install/configure
>      nutch](http://groups.drupal.org/node/105774).

For Apachesolr in Drupal 6.x, see: [Setup Drupal 6.x with Apache Solr on Tomcat6 and Ubuntu](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/setup-drupal-6x-with-apache-solr-on-tomcat6-and-ubuntu/2009-08-07).